# Access-Request-Headers en angularjs y c#

Tags: c#, angularjs

En la parte de angularjs tengo esta parte de codigo para mostrar las request-headers desde la web:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common["User"] = "MjM=";
 $http.defaults.headers.common["Password"] = "MjM=";
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/route/",

    setRequestHeader: {
        "User": $http.defaults.headers.common.User,
        "Password": $http.defaults.headers.common.Password
    }
  });
```

Estoy usando la verison 1.5.0 de angularjs.
Aparentemente desde angularjs  creo que funciona todo correcto puesto que desde chrome se visualizan ls request-headers que estamos creando aqui:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues, al irnos a nuestro codigo en c#, ponemos la correspondiente configuracion:

```
[Route("Token")]        
    [HttpGet, HttpOptions, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete]
    [AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:61291",headers:"user, password", methods:"*")]
```

Y despues de esto la funcion en la que recojo los valores de los headers, y aqui es donde esta el problema:

```
var Datos = Request.Headers;
var token = Datos.GetValues("User");
var token = Datos.GetValues("Password");
```

Despues hago un if para controlar posibles fallos, pero el problema es que la funcion GetValues de header en cuestión, devuelve siempre NULL.

Comment: Hola, en el WebApiConfig ¿tienes puesta la línea config.EnableCors();? (Supongo que sí, pero como no lo has especificado, por si acaso). Yo probaría permitiendo todos los headers (headers:"*") a ver si así llegan para ir descartando.

Comment: Puedes confirmar que no te este enviando 2 peticiones? Lo menciono por algo llamado prefight al momento de enviar una peticion y un headers custumizado a web api.

Comment: Realiza dos llamadas, una con GET y otra con OPTIONS, aunque ese error aparentemente se ha solventado poniendo un Response.flush() en c#.